# xml node retrieving value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, oracle

i am trying to migrate the following query from sql server to oracle

**sqlserver**

```
insert into @XmlGroupKeys(trans_grp_key)
SELECT KeyList.Keys.value('(.)','varchar(10)') AS GroupKey 
FROM @GroupKeyList.nodes('*') AS KeyList(Keys)
```

to oracle

```
INSERT INTO tt_v_XmlGroupKeys  ( TRANS_GRP_KEY )
SELECT KEYS GroupKey FROM 
XMLTABLE('*' PASSING v_GroupKeyList COLUMNS KEYS VARCHAR2(10) );
```

what i dont understand is @GroupKeyList.nodes('*') part in sqlserver.. what does it mean and what is an equivalent in oracle..